# What can be concluded if limit of 2 sequences multiplicaiton is 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

[image]

Need help with this specific question, and in general, what can I conclude regarding each sequence from knowing that the limit of their multiplication is zero? If one of the sequences limit is infinity, what can I tell about the other sequence?

Comment: i think only one sequence has the limit zero and the other limit is a real number

Comment: Here is an intuitive explanation of the main question: suppose we want to find where $b_n$ is small. Go out very far in the sequence $a_n$ to get a number which is almost $m$, and then go out further in the sequence $a_nb_n$ to get a number which is small times $m$. Then $b_n$ is "small, times $m$ divided by almost $m$", which is almost small. With just a little bit of care, 'almost small' is small enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $m>0$ there is $N_0$ such that $a_n>0$ for $n>N_0$

For $n>N_0$: $b_n=\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n} \to  \frac{0}{m}=0$

Answer (score 1):

For the question you have given, the answer must be yes, and here is the reason:

Let $\epsilon>0$. We will find $n$ satisfying the conditions.

Let $m>\delta>0$. We know that for sufficiently large $n$, $|a_nb_n| < \delta$ and $|a_n - m| < \delta$. This means that $a_n$ is positive for large enough $n$.

However,
$$
|a_n - m| < \delta \implies m-\delta<a_n <m+\delta  \implies  \frac{-\delta}{m-\delta}<b_n < \frac{\delta}{m+\delta} 
$$
So just pick delta small enough so that $\max \big\{\Big|\frac{-\delta}{m-\delta}\Big|,\Big|\frac{\delta}{m+\delta}\Big|\big\} > \epsilon$, then you are done. So $\lim b_n = 0$.

On the other hand, if $a_n$ diverges, then an even simpler argument will show that $b_n \to 0$. I leave you to see this.

If nothing is known about either of the sequences, then nothing can be said at all. For example, you could have a general sequence $\{a_n\}$, and the sequence $b_n = 0$ will annihilate it.